# Send image data to android app from App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In my App Engine backend I have a method that gets an image from `Google Cloud Storage`

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "getProfileImage",
        path = "image",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public Image getProfileImage(@Named("imageName")String imageName){
    try{
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();

        Storage.Builder storageBuilder = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport,new JacksonFactory(),credential);
        Storage storage = storageBuilder.build();

        Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get("mybucket", imageName);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // If you're not in AppEngine, download the whole thing in one request, if possible.
        getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(false);
        getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);

        byte[] oldImageData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();

        ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

        return ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(oldImageData);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.info("Error getting image named "+imageName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

the issue I am having is how do I get the image data when I call that in my android app?

Since you cant return primitives from app engine I converted it to an `Image` so that I could call `getImageData()` in my app to get the byte[].

However the Image object returned to the app is not the same as the one in app engine so there is no getImageData().

How can I get the image data to my android app?

If I create an Object that had a byte[] variable in it then I set the byte[] variable with the string data and return that object from the method will that work?

**Update**

The image gets sent from the android app. (this code may or may not be correct, I have not debugged it yet)

```
@WorkerThread
    public String startResumableSession(){
        try{
            File file = new File(mFilePath);
            long fileSize = file.length();
            file = null;
            String sUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/lsimages/o?uploadType=resumable&name="+mImgName;
            URL url = new URL(sUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Type","image/png");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Length",String.valueOf(fileSize));
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                return urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private long sendNextChunk(String sUrl,File file,long skip){
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 524287;
        long totalBytesSent = 0;
        try{
            long fileSize = file.length();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            skip = fileInputStream.skip(skip);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            totalBytesSent = skip + bufferSize;
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(sUrl);
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(524287);
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","image/png");
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",String.valueOf(bytesRead));
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", "bytes "+String.valueOf(skip)+"-"+String.valueOf(totalBytesSent)+"/"+String.valueOf(fileSize));

                        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                        if(code == 308){
                            String range = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Range");
                            return Integer.parseInt(range.split("-")[1]);
                        }else if(code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED){
                            return -1;
                        }

                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                        outputStream = null;
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
//                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
//                        return response;
                        return -1;
                    }
                    fileInputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
//                response = "error";
//                return response;
                return -1;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

Apparently its not clear to people that I am using Endpoints in my android app

Comment: I usually use Python so I don't know you do that in Java but you could just return the profile picture url generated from Google Cloud Storage instead of return the byte array. In that way, you could cache the profile url to avoid to rebuild it all the time.

Comment: As @Maël said you should not transfert the whole image through your stack  (for performance reasons but also to reduce your costs). Do you create the Image type ? If yes can you post its source ?

Comment: @BenoîtSauvère the images comes from the android app, I have updated the question with that code. To get the image Url dont I have to download the image data anyway? So essentially I would get downloading the image data twice, once on the server just to get the serving Url and again on the client app. Wouldnt that be more inefficient  (cost) than just getting the image data from the server? Once the android app gets the image data my plan was to cache the image locally (save it to disk) so that it does not have to go get it again

Comment: @Maël the image data would only be downloaded once then the image would be stored on the device when it needs to be displayed again. Also the idea of getting the image data from the server was to send the server a width and height of where the image is going to be displayed and the server would scale it and not force the client to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing/finding out that you need to call `execute()` on the api call with endpoints and it returns the real data passed back from the API

example

The api call returns `Image`

```
public Image getProfileImage(@Named("id") long id, @Named("imageName")String imageName){
        try{
            ProfileRecord pr = get(id);
            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();

            Storage.Builder storageBuilder = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport,new JacksonFactory(),credential);
            Storage storage = storageBuilder.build();

            Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get("mybucket", imageName);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // If you're not in AppEngine, download the whole thing in one request, if possible.
        getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(false);
        getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);

        byte[] oldImageData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        return ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(oldImageData);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.info("Error getting image named "+imageName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

then on the client side I would call it like this to get it

```
Image i = pr.profileImage(id,"name.jpg").execute();
byte[] data = i.decodeImageData();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Google Cloud Endpoints for this:

> Google Cloud Endpoints consists of tools, libraries and capabilities
>   that allow you to generate APIs and client libraries from an App
>   Engine application, referred to as an API backend, to simplify client
>   access to data from other applications. Endpoints makes it easier to
>   create a web backend for web clients and mobile clients such as
>   Android or Apple's iOS.

see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

Comment: which is what I am using so you didnt really answer my question

Comment: I am really sorry that my attempt to help you was not to your satisfaction. Maybe mentioning Endpoints in your question or tags could have avoided my intolerable misinterpretation.